# Need some advice with a class and a header file

Tags: c++, class, header-files

## What I'm trying to do?

I have two codes, a .cpp and a .h, I want to create a stack using 2 methods, POP and PUSH by calling them from the cpp

## Output errors (Updated)

error: PUSH(int val) cannot be overloaded (The same with POP() )

## Compile with g++ -Wall -O2 Stack.cpp -o Stack

## The cpp code

```
 # include < iostream >

 # include " LibStack.h "

using namespace std;
using namespace STACK;

int main()
{

Stack S1;

int elm;

cout << "Insert value:"<< endl;
cin >> elm;

S1.PUSH(elm);

S1.POP();


return 0;
}
```

## The header file

```
 # ifndef _LibStack_H_

 # define _LibStack_H_

# define MAX_STACK 10

using namespace std;
namespace STACK
{

class Stack
{

private:

    int stack[MAX_STACK];
    int MIN_STACK = 0;

public:

    void PUSH(int);
    void POP();

PUSH(int val)
{

    if(MIN_STACK < MAX_STACK)
    {
        stack[MAX_STACK+1] = val;
    }
    else
        cout << "Full stack!" << endl;
}

POP()
{

    int aux;

    if(MIN_STACK >= 0)
    {
        aux = stack--[MIN_STACK];
        cout << " POP " << endl << aux << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Empty stack!" << endl;

}

};

}
# endif // __LibStack_H_
```

Comment: `template <class Stack>` this is not how classes are declared.

Comment: Now I have more doubts, how do you declare a class using templates?

Comment: "Stack<int> S1" <-- you are missing a semicolon ";" there.

Comment: "\_\_LibStack_H_\_" - names containing double underscore "__" are reserved for the implementation and should not be used.

Comment: Thanks :), But getting the same error  expected primary-expression before 'int' and 'Stack' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Are you really pushing using MAX_STACK as index an popping out using MIN_STACK as index? MAX_STACK is always 10..Remember that. And I dnt understand why you use template and all here

Comment: This is broken at the syntactic level, you should grab a C++ book and learn syntax properly before pushing completely broken stuff to the compiler.

Comment: In addition to the answers to your question, you might want to rethink your code style. ALL UPPERCASE is usually reserved for preprocessor makros, like #define GRAVITATIONAL_CONSTANT 6.67408E-11, and therefore should not be used for variable names, methods or namespaces. You can do it otherwise, but most coding styles will differ from yours if you do.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a class like this:

```
class Stack 
{

private:

    int stack[MAX_STACK];
    int MIN_STACK = 0;

public:
. . . 
}
```

The push function can be implemented as follows:

When you increment the value of MIN_STACK before inserting, you always leave stack[0] empty and waste the space. Also use `MIN_STACK` as your index and not `MAX_STACK` as the value of `MAX_STACK` is always 10.

```
void PUSH(int val)
{
    if(MIN_STACK < MAX_STACK)
    {
        stack[MIN_STACK++] = val;
/*
Here MIN_STACK is incremented after insertion. It is the same as stack[MIN_STACK] = val;
MIN_STACK +=1;
*/

    }
    else
        cout << "Full stack!" << endl;
}
```

In POP function, you have nothing to delete if `MIN_STACK` is 0 because each time you push a value `MIN_STACK` is incremented.`MIN_STACK` always points to the next free location. SO the data to be popped out is in `(MIN_STACK-1)`th position. So decrement the  `MIN_PATH` and use it.

```
void POP()
{

    int aux;
    if(MIN_STACK > 0)
    {
        aux = stack[--MIN_STACK];

/* Here MIN_STACK is decremented before popping out. It is the same as   MIN_STACK -= 1;
        aux = stack[MIN_STACK]; */
        cout << " POP : " << aux << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "Empty stack!" << endl;

}
```

In your `cpp` file create an object of the class as:

```
Stack S1;
S1.PUSH(elm);
S1.POP();
```

Answer (score 0):

A few random points below, with no pretense to being a complete list.

`class Stack  // template <class Stack>`

`// void PUSH(int);`

`// void POP();`

`void PUSH(int val) // PUSH(int val)`

`stack[MIN_STACK++] = val; // MIN_STACK += 1; stack[MAX_STACK] = val;`

`void POP() // POP()`

`// if(MIN_STACK >= 0) { MIN_STACK -= 1; aux = stack[MIN_STACK+1];`

`if(MIN_STACK > 0) { aux = stack[--MIN_STACK];`